# Why does Simple Injector discourage for scenario's other than dynamically loading assemblies?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

In the documentation it explains that packaging is discouraged. However, I find that when I add a reference to my service project, it allows me to accidentally use the implementation rather than the interface as VS easily suggests and adds the using statements.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is the package approach discouraged? By not adding references ithe compiler enforces that unplanned d dependencies are not introduced

Comment: Please read [this](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#package-registrations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application). If you have any questions after reading those references, please update your very clear on what it you want to no comparing to the read information.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#package-registrations) states:

> SimpleInjector.Packaging is specifically designed for loading configurations from assemblies that are loaded dynamically. In other scenarios the use of Packaging is discouraged.
>
> For non-plug-in scenario’s, **all container registrations should be located as close as possible to the application’s entry point**. This location is commonly referred to as the Composition Root.

Trying to prevent the application's entry point from having a dependency on the other assemblies in the application makes no sense, because the entry-point is *by definition* the most volatile part of the application, and it will always be used to tie everything together. Since assembly dependencies are transitive, it will always depend on *all* assemblies in the application, except when you use dynamic assembly loading.

For a more detailed discussion on this, read freely available excerpt of the [Composition Root section](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) of [Dependency Injection in .NET, Second Edition](https://manning.com/seemann2/).